# How to print from flex app by clicking print in context menu

Tags: apache-flex, printing, flex4, flash

I want my flex 4 application to print proper picture when I click on print in context menu of Adobe Flash Player. Is it possible?
Proper picture - picture just a bit different then you see at the screen. I mean some colors are different.

Comment: Please clarify your question. What "proper picture" do you want to print?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "print" context menu item is not suitable for printing from Flex applications. It is more appropriate for Flash applications created with Flash Professional. You should implement your own [printing](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/printing_1.html) functionality.

If you wish to print from the context menu then you could create a [Custom "context menu" in flex](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2472358/256544) via the [ContextMenu](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/ui/ContextMenu.html) and [ContextMenuItem](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/ui/ContextMenuItem.html) classes. See also [Working with Menus](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118676a48d0-8000.html) in the [AS3 Developer's Guide](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/as3_devguide.pdf).

To change the context menu:

```
var my_cm:ContextMenu = new ContextMenu();
my_cm.hideBuiltInItems();
var printItem:ContextMenuItem = new ContextMenuItem("Print proper image");
my_cm.customItems.push(printItem);
this.contextMenu = my_cm;
```

[image: Modified Flash Context Menu]

**Don't forget** that you can't use the `"Print"` caption, because it is reserved for the internal print function (see [Restrictions](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/ui/ContextMenuItem.html)).

Comment: Unfortunately, Flash Player doesn't support NativeMenu. That is why I can't change action, which occurs when user clicks on print button of context menu (I mean right click menu).

Comment: So I can do just two things: add button inside my app to print it properly or add context menu button, right?

Comment: Great! I can hide native print button and add my own. Thank you splash!